# graphql delete mutation works in the playground but not in the frontend

Tags: graphql, strapi, apollo-boost

I have a graphql delete mutation that works perfectly with Strapi in the graphql plugin playground.
In a Vuejs frontend I cannot get the mutation to read the id of the item to delete.

The query in the graphql playground is

```
mutation deleteInvoice ($id: deleteInvoiceInput!) {
  deleteInvoice(input: $id) {
    invoice {
      id
    }
  }
}
Query variables
{ "id": "618bacab6a2a1b2f7407a8e8" }
```

The frontend display is a list with button to delete each item

```
<tr v-for="(item, id) in result.invoices" :key="id" id="delete-item">
  <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
  <button @click="onDeleteClicked(item)"  uk-icon="icon: trash"></button>
</td>
```

```
const { mutate: deleteInvoice } = useMutation(gql`
  mutation deleteInvoice($id: ID!) {
    deleteInvoice(input: { where: { id: $id } }) {
      invoice {
        id
      }    
    }
  }`, 
  (id) => ({
    variables: { id }
  })
)
const onDeleteClicked = (item) => {
deleteInvoice({ variables: { item: item.id} })
  alert(item.id)
}
```

the alert displays correctly the id of the item clicked - but the id is not passed the mutation

how to pass the id of the item clicked to the mutation?

Answer (score 0):

The variables object must contain key value pairs where the key matches a declared variable. In your case you declare the variable `id` but in the object you use the key `invoiceID`. Either rename the variable or the key.

Furthermore, you are probably confusing yourself by calling the variable `id`, even though it expects a filter input like above: `{ where: { id: "id value" } }`. The easiest way is probably to not pass in the object from JavaScript, but make your query take a variable of type `ID`:

```
mutation deleteInvoice ($id: ID!) {
  deleteInvoice(input: { where: { id: $id } }) {
    invoice {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Now this makes mutch more sense as `id` is really an ID and not a `deleteInvoiceInput`.

Bringing it all together:

```js
const [deleteInvoice] = useMutation(gql`
  mutation deleteInvoice($id: ID!) {
    deleteInvoice(input: { where: { id: $id } }) {
      invoice {
        id
      }    
    }
  }
`)

// Usually in callback
const onDeleteClicked = (event) => {
  const id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id');
  deleteInvoice({ variables: { id } });
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah it looks like a hook but the question is tagged with `vue-apollo` AND `apollo-boost`. I will edit to the actual mutation interface.

Comment: tried your suggestion but still not able to pass the id to the mutation - updated the process based the suggestions